# error in Angular12 *ngIf directive text field validation

Tags: angular, frontend

Whenever I use `*ngIf` directive to validate the text field minimum characters it gives error.

I use

```
<div *ngIf = "courseName.errors.minlength" >
    Minimum 5 characters required 
</div>
```

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGeaR.jpg)

[Error Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4rFn.jpg)

Comment: `Object is possibly null` is a fairly common error. Did you [try](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=object+is+possibly+null) [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=object+is+possibly+null) for a solution before posting the question? Also imagine if Imgur is down and someone looking for the same solution ends up here. There would be nothing helpful in the question to help them. So please avoid posting screenshots of code. Post the code here directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<div *ngIf = "courseName.errors?.minlength" >
```

And also you can check this setting in the tsconfig.json

```
"strictTemplates": true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<div *ngIf = "courseName.errors?.minlength">`. This should do the trick.